# Security for website admin panel

Tags: authentication, web-application, appsec

I am creating an admin panel for my website. I am coding the entire website by myself. What are some essential security features that I should implement so that only I can access the admin panel and no one else?

Comment: Your comment below mentions "what about a password?". If that's where you are in your design, then perhaps this is not the best site for you. The list of things you should consider, including passwords, is too long for any one answer to list. If you can refine your question to something specific, we might be better able to help. And you might want to consider looking up security design patterns and using established libraries instead of coding every single thing yourself.

Comment: Hi, I get your point. I am actually asking for a list of to-dos to ensure that my admin panel is safe.

Comment: There is no "to do list". I'm saying that you need to look at design patterns based on your context. It's like asking "what do I need to do to be healthy?". It's not answerable. Lots of endless possible lists. No answers.

Comment: Right. Got you.

Answer (score 1):

The most powerful and simplest security you could add is called mTLS (mutual TLS) combined with Let’s Encrypt for a normal certificate.

With mTLS you create a client side certificate that must be used with each connection initiated, using cryptographicly sound keys.

If you want to learn more about it smallstep have a open source ca and other tools to manage these things.

There are other ways but most offer less security for more work.

Finally any website must be secure from the standard OWASP list like XSS, sql injection l, remote code execution… etc

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. However, is there something which would be less complicated to setup? Something like requiring a password, etc.? I am still a noob when it comes to SSL and TLS, so I would like to use something which is less complicated.

Comment: @AD-1 all solutions are complicated. But there are good resources to help you like https://smallstep.com/hello-mtls setting up something else means you have to verify it works as intended, in all cases… which is hard.

Comment: I got your point.